# Why is my sqlite3 file never being created?

Tags: c, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to create a sqlite3 database in Xcode.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    printf("called here");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int result = sqlite3_open("noodle.sqlite3", &db);

    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("did not work\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    char *sql = "CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME TEXT NOT NULL);";
    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("heya");
        exit(0);
    }

    char *sql2 = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 'NEATO');";
    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql2, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("dangit");
        exit(0);
    }

    const char* data = "Callback function called";
    char *sql3 = "SELECT * FROM TEST;";
    result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql3, callback, (void *)data, &zErrMsg);

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm following [this tutorial](http://milky.manishsinha.net/2009/03/30/sqlite-with-c/). But the directory that I have my `main.c` file in never sees the creation of a `noodle.sqlite3` file.

What am I doing wrong? I thought `sqlite3_open` creates the database if one doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're seeing your error message, it probably *is* creating the file, but probably not where you're looking for it.

Because you don't specify the folder in which the file should be placed, the file will generally be in the "current working directory". If you run it from a Terminal window, that will be whatever folder you ran it from. If you're running this from Xcode, the "current working folder" could be the folder in which the executable product has been placed, which you can identify by right clicking on the "product" and choosing "Show in Finder":

[image].

I've also seen it create file in the Documents folder.

Bottom line, if you don't see the file, search your Mac using the Finder's search feature and look for "name:noodle", and you should find it that way.

Frankly, I would take the ambiguity out of the process, and explicitly tell it to save the file in the documents folder:

```
NSString *documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"noodle.sqlite3"];

sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int result = sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db);
```